# Use Open vSwitch without VM

Tags: networking

The standart use of OVS is to connect host adapters with OVS and connect OVS with virtual machines adapters. But I want to use OVS as a layer between host and host's adapters. I didn't find anything about this way of OVS use. Can anybody explain how to do that or provide some links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simple.
Firstly just add bridge:

```
ovs-vsctl add-br br0
```

Then add port with your default internet interface (in my case it's eth0):

```
ovs-vsctl add-port eth0
```

Your internet connection will be lost.
Then remove IP from default interface (remember previous IP!):

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
```

Then put IP that you remembered on br0:

```
ifconfig br0 192.168.0.100
```

if you use static IP-addressing or use

```
dhclient br0
```

if you use DHCP.

That's all!